# Explain what is meant in the article

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind, explanation

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#BestExpl

"But he also makes the following, important, observation: “A complete response to the problem of other minds seems obliged to incorporate more than one approach, and may have to incorporate several”. This is an observation others have also begun to advocate"

What does it mean?

Need more arguments?

Thank you

Comment: That the argument is no longer considered cogente.

Comment: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#BestExpl

"Melnyk can be read as advocating a hybrid account of our knowledge here, incorporating elements from the argument from analogy as a supplement to the inference from best explanation. But he also makes the following, important, observation: “A complete response to the problem of other minds seems obliged to incorporate more than one approach, and may have to incorporate several”. This is an observation others have also begun to advocate" - Could you explain what that means?